# change color of icon react with gradient

Tags: css, reactjs

I imported the Instagram icon from react icons (SiInstagram from Simple Icons) into my app.css, and now I'm trying to change the color of my Instagram icon to match the current colors of the social media icon. However, I can only use linear-gradient to create the color effect on its background, not on its actual color. Is there any way to achieve the same color effect but on the "color:;" property?

[image: icon]

E assim era como eu gostaria que ficasse

[image]

APP.JS

```
import { SlSocialInstagram } from "react-icons/sl";

return (
    <div className="div-app">
      <div className="container-app">
        <div className="content">
            <div className="contact-div">
              <ul className="contact-ul">
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    <BsFillTelephoneFill />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    <BsFillEnvelopeFill />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    <TbMessageCircle2Filled />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <IconContext.Provider
                    value={{ color: "blue", className: "global-class-name" }}
                  >
                  <a href="">
                    <SlSocialInstagram id="instagram-icon" />
                  </a>
                  </IconContext.Provider>
                  ;
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

APP.CSS

```
.contact-div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 150px 0 0 40px;
}

.contact-ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-ul li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.contact-ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#instagram-icon {

  background-image: url("./assets/headset.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TailwindCSS

Ex: `<div className="h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 to-pink-500"></div>`
or just `<div class="h-14 bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 to-pink-500"></div>`

will gave you the result as

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULWAz.png)

Below is the link for your concern

[Link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image)

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an older post, but there isn't an answer yet and after researching the topic for my own purposes, I decided to share my findings.

To my understanding, there isn't a convenient method of applying a gradient to the `color` property in react-icons. There are, however, some unconventional methods of accomplishing this.

[react-icons issue #251 on GitHub](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/251)

There's a walkthrough on [creating a painter component](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/issues/251#issuecomment-763039938) that *might* suit your needs.